# django front end customization by designer (without modifying view or form)

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I'd really like my front end colleague to handle CSS and other front end things -- indeed, a design principle of django is this separation, that they can mostly modify templates and not need me to change code.  And yet, too often it seems the only way I can find to modify a form is on the backend side (in a view, model, or form).  For views provided by packages (e.g., registration) it's even more bothersome, because frequently this is the only modification of the provided python code.

Example: in `registration/login.html` (which is a template, so I don't much mind providing my own) I have this

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}<br>
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}"></label> {{ form.username }}<br>
    {{ form.password.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"></label> {{ form.password }}
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Me connecter" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

I'd really like placeholder text (the word "password" in light gray in the password field, for example).  And so I find myself making a `forms.py` so that I can write

```
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password', ...
```

And this keeps repeating every time the front end guys want to change something in a form, which just can't be right.

To be clear, I want to change the template so that where we have

```
{{ form.password.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"></label> {{ form.password }}
```

we can instead write something that is just html, css, and the *contents* of the form variable.  Something like this (which isn't right):

```
{{ form.password.errors.text }}
<label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"></label>
<input id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"
    name="{{ form.password.name }}"
    placeholder="password"
    type="password" />
```

And maybe a variant on that is what is needed, but then I don't understand why no examples I've seen do that.

What am I missing about django so that such frontend tasks don't require backend intervention?

Comment: Have you tried embedding the inputs in `div` or `span` that have a `class` or `id` attribute, so that the front-end guy can play with this in the css. This might allow less change on the back-end side.

Comment: @nnaelle - I don't follow you, my front end colleague can certainly do that.  I've updated the question (at the end) to make clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having consulted with a few colleagues, it seems the most likely thing to do is this

```
{{ form.password.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"></label>
<input id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"
   name="{{ form.password.name }}"
   placeholder="password"
   type="password" />
```

It's a reasonable balance between letting django do the work and so being robust against future changes in the package vs requiring much modification by package users.  It is what we're now doing.

It might be possible to write a template filter.  That's out of scope for this week's activities for me, but it would certainly be nifty if one could write something like this:

```
{{ form.password.errors }}
{{ form.password | attrs placeholder="password" }}
```